# How do I consume an existing webservice in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to consume an existing web service in ASP.net.

The documentation of the website that provides the web servicesays that I have to use  WSDL.exe to generate a stub, but I can't find this tool.

I also tried the `Add web reference wizard` in Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010), but if I paste the URL in, VS2010 doesn't work anymore.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you need to generate a service proxy classes?

Comment: You'll need plenty of water or the web service will get scummy.

Comment: @Elalfer: I think so, I never done this before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also try using the Add Service Reference Wizard instead - worked for me for WebServices the Web Reference Wizard did not like quite as much. Make sure to use the link to either the asmx (if it's one) or the .wsdl

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember there should be a choice between `.net 2.0` and `WCF` services.

Try to select `.net 2.0` web service type. We had to do it for using `SOAP` web services running on Python.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't create SOAP webservice with .net 4. When you creating new project, you need to choos .net 3.5 or earlier first, and then create project.

As for creating stub from existing wsdl, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's not creating a webservice but using one